# who to plot stats.probplot in a grid?

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have a data frame with four columns I would like to plot the normality test for each column in a 2*2 grid, but it only plot one figure, and the else is empty.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(15, 6), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .5, wspace=.001)

data = {'col1': [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(1000)], 'col2': [random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(1000)],'col3':[random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(1000)]
,'col4':[random.randrange(1, 50, 1) for i in range(1000)]}  

df = pd.DataFrame(data)  


for ax, d in zip(axs.ravel(), df):
    ax=stats.probplot(df[d], plot=plt)
    #ax.set_title(str(d))

plt.show()
```

is there a way to construct the `subplot` and the `stats.probplot` within a loop?

Comment: it gave me this error `probplot() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ax'` and I reviewed the dicumaantaion the `probplot` don't have ax as an argument

Comment: `stats.probplot(df[d], plot=ax)` according to the documentation

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you need to change the for loop to this:

```
for ax, d in zip(axs.ravel(), df):

       stats.probplot(df[d], plot=ax)

       #ax.set_titl(str(d))

plt.show()
```

I hope this will help you move on.